# How to filter copy paste string objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

Is there any way to filter copied text/string into `UITextField`?
I already tried to use `UITextField` method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, but it only filter when we type in it, but when we paste to it, it still can't be filtered. I want `UITextField` only can input by alphanumeric, but it still can input by other char via copy paste.

here is a piece of my code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
if (textField == _nameField) {
NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NAME_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called even when the user pastes into the field.

If you're struggling to do what you need inside that function, an easy hack is to do this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self textFieldDidUpdate:textField];
    });

    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidUpdate:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Filter and reset your textfield content
}
```

It's not ideal but it gets the job done.

Comment: I get error 'too few arguments to function to call'

Comment: Sorry, one too many parentheses. I've edited the `dispatch_after` snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    BOOL valid = [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet] isEqualToString:@""];
    return valid;
}
```

To get a string of only alpha numerics you can use this

```
NSCharacterSet *unwantedCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSLog(@"%@",[[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: unwantedCharacters] componentsJoinedByString: @""]);
```

However then you would have do some manipulation yourself in the field.

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only trims characters from each end of the string.

Comment: It trims whenever the character on either end is an alphanumeric. If they are all alphanumeric, the resulting string is @"". For example if it trimmed "asdf-ret-tr" this would return "-ret-" which is not "".

Comment: Sure, but if the string is "%d&ghj*" that would return NO, and therefore not update the field at all. The requirement is to _filter_ non-alphanumerics, i.e. to return YES but only update with "dghj".